# How to use protocolous.js (Prototype.js and Scriptaculous.js )?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Protoculous Documentation](http://protoculous.wikeo.be/)
    I read this document but i can't undestand how to use this js, and what is benefits of this js. 
Any one can if know much more about this js.

Please let me know .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This seems to be a library from 2011, so I would not recommend using it at all. What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: Please dont use this combo library. If you want to use Prototype and Scripty, please download the most recent versions (Prototype 1.7.3) and Scripty 1.9.0. The biggest difference between other JS libraries is Prototype adds a lot of connivence methods to vanilla JS, and smooths out discrepancies between missing methods in older browsers. I would suggest starting at http://script.aculo.us/ and http://prototypejs.org/learn/